# CSV reader string to float in python

Tags: python, string, file, csv

I'm using this function to read in a csv file but I want to convert it from strings to floats. I'm not sure where to insert. When I try I usually get an error that ' float' object has no attribute 'getitem'

```
def getColumn(filename, column):
   results = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter=',')
   next(results, None)
   return [result[column] for result in results]
```

Comment: What programming language are you using? Please add a proper tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

def get_column(filename, column):
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        results = []

        for row in reader:
            entry = row[column]

            try:
                results.append(float(entry))
            except ValueError:
                print(
                    "Could not convert '{}' to "
                    "a float...skipping.".format(entry)
                )

        return results

result = get_column('csv.csv', 'num')

print(result)
print(sum(result))


--output:--
Could not convert 'mars' to a float...skipping.
[3.1, 2.6]
5.7
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you are using Python. You can simply parse a String to a float, such as:

```
a = "42.23"
float(a)
```